# SPARQL get all the data before it reaches timeout

Tags: timeout, sparql, wikidata

I am trying to get **all the city names** of **all countries** in the world using this below query. Whenever I execute this below query it returns this message `"Query timeout limit reached"`.

Is there any other way to get all the data before it reaches timeout limit?

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?city ?cityLabel
WHERE
{
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515;
        wdt:P17 ?country .

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
ORDER BY ?country
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is a way around the timeout. The alternative is to break the query up into multiple queries and write some code that will run all the queries. That is, first get all the countries and then run the above query for each country.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse Yeah. I have that idea too. But, sad part is I need to run the query for 220 times.. :-(

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse I tried without the ORDER BY as philshem said in his first comment (https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15641/sparql-get-all-the-data-before-it-reaches-timeout?noredirect=1#comment18580_15641). It is working fine now.

Comment: honestly, it's weird. I know that `ORDER BY` is always expensive, but in your query there are `64255` cities, that's a tiny number to sort by country then ... for me an issue in the query optimizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not at all sure why, but, this query works for me:

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?city ?cityLabel
WHERE
{
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515;
        wdt:P17 ?country .

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
LIMIT 100000
```

The two differences from your original query are:

1. Ordering by `countryLabel` is, I'm guessing, what you actually wanted instead of ordering by `country`. In my experience ordering by label is sometimes faster too.
2. I set a limit number. The query appears to return results of the same length as it would without a limit, since the limit is higher than the proper number of results.

Comment: Thanks for this useful trick. Is there any way to exclude this kind of results `countryLabel: Q11916644` & `cityLabel: Q20108173`? If any one of the city or country label contains this `QXXXXXXXX` it should be excluded from results.

Comment: I don't know yet, but I would like to. Ask a new question about it and I'll look into it.

Comment: honestly, the query does not always work. I tried right now and got a timeout. I also don't see why this query should be faster. Given the ORDER BY, the whole data has to be computed first and pushing the LIMIT into some intermediate result won't work. I think at just works sometimes by chance given that the whole endpoint is a public shared service with different load at different time. Just my two cents ...

Comment: excluding labels like `Q11916644` returned from the label service is only possible via a) regex because this is the expected fallback in case there is no such label in the specified language or b) you have to get the labels the "normal" way in SPARQL

Comment: I also see no reason why it should be faster. I agree that the appearance of it being faster could be chance, and indeed that it does not work every time. I guess a person would have to benchmark it to be sure. Filtering out `Qxxxx` labels seems possible with `FILTER(EXISTS {
    ?item schema:description ?itemdesc.
    FILTER(LANG(?itemdesc) = "en")
  })`

Answer (score 2):

I've posted this [answer on the Open Data site](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/15648/1511), based on my comment, but removing `ORDER BY` made the query go through.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query that works using our recently released [Wikidata SPARQL Query Service endpoint](https://wikidata.demo.openlinksw.com/sparql).

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

SELECT distinct ?country ?countryLabel ?city ?cityLabel
WHERE
{
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515;
        wdt:P17 ?country ;
        rdfs:label ?cityLabel . 
  FILTER (lang(?cityLabel) = "en")

  ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel .
  FILTER (lang(?countryLabel) = "en")

}
ORDER BY ?country
```

[Live Query Results Page](https://wikidata.demo.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2F&query=PREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20bd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bigdata.com%2Frdf%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20distinct%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ515%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FcityLabel%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28lang%28%3FcityLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FcountryLabel%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28lang%28%3FcountryLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fcountry&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20).

Comment: Cool! What can you tell us about this newly-released endpoint as compared to https://query.wikidata.org/?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that works.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?cityID ?cityIDLabel ?countryID ?countryIDLabel WHERE 
{
  {
    SELECT * WHERE 
    {
      ?cityID wdt:P31 ?cityInstance.
      VALUES (?cityInstance) {
        (wd:Q515)
        (wd:Q5119)
      }
      OPTIONAL {
        ?cityID wdt:P17 ?countryID.
        ?countryID p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q6256.
      }

      FILTER NOT EXISTS {
        ?cityID wdt:P17 "".
        ?countryID wdt:P30 "".
      }
    }
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
ORDER BY ?countryIDLabel
```

Comment: ehm, what is the advantage of your query here? using inline data via `VALUES` would also make the query on the question working.

Comment: also, what is the purpose of the `FILTER NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: the advantage is that it doesn't time out due to how the query is structured and orders the results by country. `FILTER NOT EXISTS` filters just does a bit of data cleaning where some empty triples are filtered out (there are some).

Comment: your query returns `8819` results while there are much more cities in Wikidata according to this query: `SELECT (count(distinct ?city) as ?cnt)
WHERE
{
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515;
        wdt:P17 ?country .

  
}` which returns `64257` - the reason is obvious, you limited the query to just 2 (sub)classes of city, there are much more like town etc.

Comment: Also your `FILTER` is literally useless given that `""` denotes the empty string literal and there are neither countries (`wdt:P17`) nor continents (`Wdt:P30`) expressed by a literal given that both are object properties. You can check with `SELECT (count(distinct ?city) as ?cnt)
WHERE
{
  ?city    wdt:P17 "".}`

Comment: @joedavid It returns less number of cities.

Comment: @KaruppiahRK I think you should explicitly list your sub classes as there are many sub-classes that wont be relevant to  you. This query returns all the 221 sub-classes of `city`: `SELECT ?subclassLabel WHERE {  ?subclass wdt:P279* wd:Q515; SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }}`. As you will see there are many incorrect ones (like municipalities) or many that would be not be relevant in your application like small towns, villages, etc. so you I would suggest to include those you need until the query returns a sufficient number of cities.

Comment: @joedavid Yeah Agreed. But, why some of the `cityIDLabel` name showing like this `Q37819251` instead of city name?

Comment: just like wikipedia, wikidata can be edited too. So I assume someone has input incorrect information. That or, these are entries without labels https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3559100. As you can see in the link someone has left the entry incomplete but is still an instance of city.

Comment: the expression `FILTER NOT EXISTS {
        ?cityID wdt:P17 "".
        ?countryID wdt:P30 "".
      }` is still useless, there are no string literals for those properties ...